# Non-blocking data transfer between separate C and Javascript processes

Tags: javascript, c, transfer

### The Goal

I have two processes running:

1. Node.js server which handles external communication (to other computers)
2. C code which runs in an infinite loop doing real-time processing

The node.js server will receive data from an external computer, send it to the C code (which is already running), wait for a reply, and send that reply back to an external computer.

HOWEVER, the C code cannot wait for input from the node.js server. It needs to be continuously running using the most recent data from the js code (updating those recent values each time new data is received). In other words, the C code needs non-blocking input from the node.js server. The node.js server should get an event (bound to a callback) each time the C code periodically sends it information back.

### What I have done

- The node.js code already handles external IO correctly (it's fairly complete)
- The C code in isolation does the task I want, just without getting data from the node.js code

I am now trying to combine them so that the C code gets its sensor data from the node.js code (as I described above).

### How I think I can do it

My current best guess of how to do this is using sockets (I think they're non-blocking?). I've never done this before, though, so before I spend a bunch of time learning about how sockets work, and writing a bunch of code, I want to make sure that this is a method which might actually work. So, I want to see if anyone has any suggestions on the easiest way to achieve what I described. If it does turn out to be sockets than at least I know I'm not wasting my time. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I mean, I'd probably spawn the node process as a child process of the C program in a separate thread and then communicate over stdin/out/err pipes.  The core piece here is the inter-process communication (IPC).  I think your question may be too broad without an attempt at the actual IPC in question.

Comment: Check out using a local MQ server like RabbitMQ to communicate messages in a queue based manner.

Comment: Sockets can be used in either blocking or non-blocking mode. What is that infinite loop actually doing? Is it CPU bound (doing calculations) or IO bound (waiting for input/output from other systems) most of the time?

Comment: @melpomene It's doing a bunch of math (using the most recent sensor data). When it gets new sensor data I want it to use those values instead, and also send out its most recent calculation back to the node.js process.

Comment: Sounds like you could use two threads, one for calculations and one for (possibly even blocking) I/O.